# C#: Searching a text in Word and getting the range of the result

Tags: c#, ms-word, find

I can find a text in a Word file via:

```
Word.Range range = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Content;
Word.Find find = range.Find;
find.Text = "xxx";
find.ClearFormatting();
find.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

This tells me if the text is found. But I need the range of the found text-piece.

Comment: Earlier in code: private object missing = Type.Missing;

Comment: Not sure about you guys/girls, but I found this API to be a bit confusing at first. I would expect `range.Find.Execute(..)` to return a new range object rather than changing the one at the root (`Document.Content`).

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried this:

```
 range.Find.Execute(
      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);


 while (range.Find.Found) 
{ 
   //Get selected index.
   // Do as you please with range...
   //Positions:  range.Start... range.End
   //search again
   range.Find.Execute(
      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, 
      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
      ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

Comment: You say in your code "//Get selected index." Can you please post code here? You're assuming people know how to get selected index.

Answer (score 5):

The range object should be changed by executing find on it.

So, likely you'd use `range.Start` and `range.End` to get the character positions.
[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range_members%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Gets a range from word using find method and format it.

```
//Parameter contains what you want to find.
_wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(title); 

Word.Range range = _wordApp.Selection.Range;
if (range.Text.Contains(title))
{
     //gets desired range here it gets last character to make superscript in range 
     Word.Range temprange = _document.Range(range.End - 1, range.End);          
     temprange.Select();
     Word.Selection currentSelection = _wordApp.Selection;
     currentSelection.Font.Superscript = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`range.Find.Execute` returns `true` if found, and sets `range` to the found range:

```
var range = doc.Range();
while ( range.Find.Execute("xxx") ) 
    Debug.Print( range.Text );
```

Note that `range.Find.Execute` will search the range after `range` if `range` is already a match for the Find conditions (after the first `range.Find.Execute`).

For example, this VBA Macro will find only the second "b" :

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveDocument.Range.Text = "abba"
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveDocument.Range(1, 2) ' the first "b"
    Debug.Print r.Start; r.End      ' prints " 1  2 "

    Debug.Print r.Find.Execute("b") ' prints "True"
    Debug.Print r.Start; r.End      ' prints " 2  3 "

    Debug.Print r.Find.Execute("b") ' prints "False" (if r.Find.Wrap = wdFindStop)
    Debug.Print r.Start; r.End      ' prints " 2  3 "
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved like this：

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Find all
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="range"></param>
    /// <param name="findText">Find content</param>
    public static List<Range> FindAll(this Range range, string findText)
    {
        int start = range.Start;
        int end = range.End;

        List<Range> ranges = new List<Range>();

        range.Find.Execute(FindText: findText, MatchCase: true);
        while (range.Find.Found)
        {
            //The search will change the range, here is an out-of-range judgment
            if (range.Start > end)
                break;

            ranges.Add(range.Document.Range(range.Start, range.End));
            range.Find.Execute(FindText: findText, MatchCase: true);
        }

        //Restore the original range
        range.SetRange(start, end);
        return ranges;
    }
```

You can also create an extension method：

```
        /// <summary>
    /// 查找第一个
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="range"></param>
    /// <param name="findText">查找内容</param>
    /// <returns>没有找到为空</returns>
    public static Range FindFirst(this Range range, string findText)
    {
        int start = range.Start;
        int end = range.End;

        bool isOk = range.Find.Execute(FindText: findText, MatchCase: true);
        if (isOk)
        {
            var newRange = range.Document.Range(range.Start, range.End);
            range.SetRange(start, end);
            return newRange;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Please, remember this is a english website