# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, bold

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word with C#. I know that you can set the text to be bold by using Range.Font.Bold=1. My problem is that I have a long sentence and I have to make some words bold in it, not the whole sentence. If my sentence is "Would you like to have responses to your questions sent to you via email?", I would like "have responses" to be bold.

With this example I can bold only one word (by looping through the whole word document):

```
foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range w in oDoc.Words)
{
    if (w.Text == "Something")
         w.Font.Bold = 1;
}
```

But this is just for one word, how can I make bold two, three or more consecutive words in a sentence.

Answer (score 3):

No need to loop through the whole document. Use Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, something similar to this:

```
private void SearchReplace()
{
    Word.Find findObject = Application.Selection.Find;
    findObject.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Text = "find me";
    findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
    findObject.Replacement.Text = "Found";

    object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
    findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
}
```

You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f65x8z3d.aspx

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

[C#: Searching a Text in Word an getting the range of the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016960/c-searching-a-text-in-word-an-getting-the-range-of-the-result)

Then you can make bold the found range.