# How to bold strings in a text

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

My question is similiar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944437/replacing-text-between-b-and-b-with-bold-text-in-c-sharp

I want to bold strings between <*strong> tags

I get the strings with

```
string pattern = @"<strong>(.*?)</strong>";
var matches = Regex.Matches(paragraf2.Range.Text, pattern)
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                   .ToList();
```

I guess I need something like

```
foreach( string a in matches)
{     
}
```

But I couldn't figure out what to write inside.

Comment: What did you try? Your tag seems to suggest that you are putting the resulting text into a Word document. Is that right?

Comment: @KevinS yes. what I want is to find stronged text (which matches gives me list of strings) and replace with bolded texts in the word document.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840199/c-sharp-microsoft-office-interop-word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as har07 stated in comments you can use it like

```
       string pattern = @"<strong>(.*?)</strong>";
       var matches = Regex.Matches(paragraf2.Range.Text, pattern)
               .Cast<Match>()
               .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
               .ToList();
       Word.Find findObject = Application.Selection.Find;
       foreach( string a in matches){ 
            findObject.ClearFormatting();
            findObject.Text = a;
            findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
            findObject.Replacement.Font.Bold = 1;
            object replaceAll = Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
            findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);  
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pertinent to your case (if described correctly), you can use the solution given in [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944437/replacing-text-between-b-and-b-with-bold-text-in-c-sharp ] by modifying the string:

```
 richTextBox1.SelectedText = richTextBox1.SelectedText.Replace("<b>", "").Replace("</b>", "");
```

like shown below:

```
richTextBox1.SelectedText = richTextBox1.SelectedText.Replace("<strong>", String.Empty).Replace("</strong>", String.Empty);
```

Or, the corresponding solution (modified original) like the following:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string regexString = "(?<=<strong>)(.*?)(?=</strong>)";
    Match matches = (Regex.Match(richTextBox1.Text, regexString));

    if (matches.Success)
    {
        int index1 = richTextBox1.Find("<strong>");
        int index2 = richTextBox1.Find("</strong>");
        richTextBox1.Select(index1 + 3, ((index2) - (index1 + 3)));

        richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont.FontFamily, richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
    }
}
```

For more details on font properties of the RichTextBox refer to the following code snippet (from Microsoft documentation online http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont%28v=vs.100%29.aspx ):

```
private void ToggleBold()
{
   if (richTextBox1.SelectionFont != null)
   {
      System.Drawing.Font currentFont = richTextBox1.SelectionFont;
      System.Drawing.FontStyle newFontStyle;

      if (richTextBox1.SelectionFont.Bold == true)
      {
         newFontStyle = FontStyle.Regular;
      }
      else
      {
         newFontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
      }

      richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(
         currentFont.FontFamily, 
         currentFont.Size, 
         newFontStyle
      );
   }
}
```

Rgds,

Comment: I dont want to just delete them all, I need them in bold.

Comment: sadly it is not working there is no range.SelectionFont or range.Text.SelectionFont