# Checking if word document contains a specified word

Tags: c#, string, search, interop, document

I need a method which would tell me if a specific word is in a word document<sup>*</sup>.

```
private bool Check(Document doc, string givenWord){
  ...
  //checking if doc contains givenWord;
  ...
  return true/false?
}
```

Is it better to convert the .doc to .rtf and avoid using Interop in terms of speed? And any ideas how that would look like?

<sup>* The document has one word per line.</sup>

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016960/c-searching-a-text-in-word-and-getting-the-range-of-the-result)?

Comment: I guess it may be, but I don't get it to be honest. I have never used Interop.