# How to use Word.Find.execute command in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I want to search a few characters like **"%"** or **"&"** or **"@"** in a Word Document with hundreds of lines. 
Word has **Find.execute** method which is used to search the strings in Documents but I am unable to use it.

Please anyone help me in searching these characters using **Find.execute** method and also I want to know the **index/range** of the character found.

I need sample code, the implementation of the Find.execute method according to my requirement. Thanks

I found that you have to edit the actual Range. so code like this will work. 
Unsure how much you have done but first thing is first

## **Initiate the application**

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new 
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
     application.Visible = false;
```

## **Open Document**

```
 Document document = application.Documents.Open(docPath);
```

## **Sift through  your document to replace characters**

#### My goal is just to show you a working model and you can take this and do what you will. I will warn you that it HAS to be the actual Range you edit or it will not work as intended unles the Visible property is true.

I also kind of used Sentences since the document I was using was done in many lines but you can create your own range of course

```
     int countss = 0;


foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range docRange in document.Word)
        {
            try
            {
               if( docRange.Text.Trim().Equals("[Date]", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found this for real!!");
                    docRange.Text = docRange.Text.Replace("[Date]", "replaced");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ee)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("error {0}", ee.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("replaced word at position {0} = {1}", countss, docRange.Text);
            countss++;

        }
```

## **Save in a new spot and go confirm your changes.**

```
document.SaveAs(FileName: @"C:\Test\NewDocument.docx");
        application.Quit();
```

Comment: Hello,
where excactly is your problem ?
Do you like to have a sample or did you not found the official documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute.aspx

Comment: Yes I need  sample code, the implementation of the Find.execute method according to my requirement. Thanks

Comment: If you just Need sample code, just have a look at the MSDN tutorials:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f1f367bx.aspx

Comment: I have gone through it. Those samples aren't enough to my requirements.
**Ques.1** - How do I pass more than 1 character in findText ?
**Ques.2** - how do I loop through the whole document to search each character one by one in the Document. (I need to display aal the characters one by one on button press) ?

Comment: Please check this- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1f367bx.aspx and this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016960/c-searching-a-text-in-word-and-getting-the-range-of-the-result